# How do I check equality between `&#039;` and '?

Tags: javascript, html, encoding

I'm quite new to web dev and am giving my very first steps in AJAX functions and HTTP requests.

I only know vanilla JS, CSS and HTML. I also know very very little about regExps so would really appreciate if answers could respect this.

I'm developing a simple quiz game where I fetch Q&As from opentdb. The data is saved in an array of questions with the following format **(notice the `&#039;` on `correct-answer`)**:

```
[..., {
category: "Entertainment: Film",
type: "multiple",
difficulty: "medium",
question: "What Queen song plays during the final fight scene of the film &quot;Hardcore Henry&quot;?",
correct_answer: "Don&#039;t Stop Me Now",
incorrect_answers: [
"Brighton Rock",
"Another Bites the Dust",
"We Will Rock You"
]
}, ...]
```

After having successfully fetched the data the first thing I do is to put all the correct answers in an array which I use later to compare with the user's selected answer. My array of correct answers, in this example would be something like **(again notice the `&#039;`)**:

```
[... ,"Don&#039;t Stop Me Now", ...]
```

When I render the questions and answers to the DOM, by creating the necessary elements and using innerHTML everything shows up well on the browser (i.e. instead of `&#039;` I get the actual `'`.

However, later, when I'm collecting the user's selected answer with:

```
const selectedAnswer = event.currentTarget.innerHTML
```

I get `"Don't Stop Me Now"` and when I compare this with my array of correct answers, I get something like:

```
"Don&#039;t Stop Me Now" === "Don't Stop Me Now"
```

which returns false when, in fact should be true because is the correct answer...

How do I solve this?

Comment: You could add some kind of flag to the button/element you assign the correct value to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well `&#039;` is a HTML Entity. So I create a new element, then set its `innerHTML` property to the text with the HTML entity then compare it's `innerText` with the user's input.

```js
const text = "Don&#039;t Stop Me Now";
const checkAnswer = (correct, input) => Object.assign(document.createElement('span'), { innerHTML: correct }).innerText == input;
console.log(checkAnswer(text, "Don't Stop Me Now"));
```

Answer (score 0):

`&#039;` is HTML Entity code for `'`. so if this only what you concern, you could try to map that array first and replace/convert that HTML Entity code into character, like this:

```js
[... ,"Don&#039;t Stop Me Now", ...].map(item => item.replace(/&#039;/g, "'"));
```

Comment: This wouldn't work because the answers can have other HTML Entity codes like `&#8220;` for `"` and others :/

Comment: what about using third party library like this https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-entities? have you try it?

Answer (score -1):

You could try using backticks instead of the HTML code for `'`.

```
[... ,`Don't Stop Me Now`, ...]
```

Comment: Either this wouldn't work because `"Don&#039;t Stop Me Now"` is what I get from the API or I'm not following...

Comment: I am sorry, I misunderstood the fact that you got this information from the API.